# Is there a way to create an executable that runs Python and R scripts?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, exe, executable

I am in the following situation and in possession of the following files:

- R script that preprocesses my data
- Python script that takes in the processed data (ran with R above) and outputs predictions from various models

Due to the lack of time I am unable to rewrite the preprocessing or modelling so that I have a standalone script in a single language.

My objective is to have an executable that runs all of the above processes (performed in R & Python).

To add on, I know how to create Python and R executables for each script.

Is it possible to create such an executable that runs both the R and Python scripts?

Comment: Perhaps you can try calling external commands via Python to execute the R script. I'm assuming that the data processed by R is saved to a file or DB that Python can access, rather than passing it in memory during execution.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @JeremyHue Thanks for your valuable input. Just to clarify, do you mean something like <main() function in master Python script to execute subprocess> => <subprocess to run R script> => <run Python script>?

Comment: @JeremyHue Or is there some sequence at which I have to call the subprocess? I apologize for any confusion that I may have caused..

Comment: Just from my understanding of what you want to do, you need to:
1. Execute R script to pre-process data
2. Execute Python script to get outputs from data

So having both scripts execute via subprocess in a separate Python script could work.

Alternatively, you could add execution of the R script (as an executable) as the first thing in the Python script that takes in the processed data.

Comment: @JeremyHue Got it, thanks. I'll try to work it out and update this thread should I encounter further problems or when I am able to complete the task.